# Pandas- Adding a specific amount of weeks to a date

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, time

I want to add a new column in a df which adds a week to a previous date.

What I have :

```
start_date         num_of_weeks      

01/5/2019.        1

01/12/2019.       2
01/12/2019.       2

01/19/2019.       3. 
01/19/2019.       3
01/19/2019.       3
```

For the num_of_weeks corresponding to each start_date I want to add one week ( 7 days) to that date.

So If num_of_weeks = 3 then

```
week1 = start_date + 7
week2 = week1 +7
week3 = week2 + 7
```

** Desired Output = **

```
start_date         num_of_weeks          weeks

01/5/2019.        1                      01/12/2019

01/12/2019.       2                      01/19/2019
01/12/2019.       2                      01/26/2019

01/19/2019.       3.                     01/26/2019
01/19/2019.       3.                     02/04/2019
01/19/2019.       3                      02/11/2019
```

Answer (score 1):

First, we'll group by `"start_date"` and create some kind of "subindex" to assign a number to each row by using [`pd.Series.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html#pandas-dataframe-rank). This new value will show us how many weeks to add to each row:

```
>> df["extra_weeks"] = df.groupby("start_date").rank("first", ascending=False)
>> df
  start_date  num_of_weeks  extra_weeks
0 2019-01-05             1          1.0
1 2019-01-12             2          1.0
2 2019-01-12             2          2.0
3 2019-01-19             3          1.0
4 2019-01-19             3          2.0
5 2019-01-19             3          3.0
```

Now, you could use [`pd.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html#pandas-to-timedelta) on the `"extra_weeks"` column and add that result to your `"start_date"` column:

```
>> df["weeks"] = df["start_date"] + pd.to_timedelta(df["extra_weeks"], unit="w")
>> df
  start_date  num_of_weeks  extra_weeks      weeks
0 2019-01-05             1          1.0 2019-01-12
1 2019-01-12             2          1.0 2019-01-19
2 2019-01-12             2          2.0 2019-01-26
3 2019-01-19             3          1.0 2019-01-26
4 2019-01-19             3          2.0 2019-02-02
5 2019-01-19             3          3.0 2019-02-09
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good opportunity to leverage the [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library.  Specifically you'll be interested in the relativedelta function.